# How to set picture to bottom layer in PPT?

Tags: python-pptx

There are Text and Picture in one slide of PPT. I would like to set Picture to bottom layer/set Text to top layer and see Text content. How to do that?

```
text_frame = shape.text_frame
text_frame.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.TOP

text_frame = shape.text_frame
text_frame.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.TOP
text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].text = "text"

left = Inches(5)
height = Inches(5.5)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img_path, left, top, height=height)
```

Let Picture in bottom layer and Text in top layer in PPT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layers on the slide will appear as per the sequence in the code. It can be customized by defining the layer depth as per the requirement.

```
from pptx import Presentation, shapes, slide
from pptx.util import Inches

img_path = 'image.png'

prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Hello, World!"
subtitle.text = "Welcome to python-pptx!"

left = Inches(1)
height = Inches(4)
width = Inches(6)
top = Inches(1)
picture = slide.shapes.add_picture(img_path, left, top, height=height)

# Using layer sequence number to customize the depth 
# sending the picture back in this case

slide.shapes._spTree.insert(2, picture._element)

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Comment: It works. Currently, I can set Picture to the bottom layer. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice @MIAlam! :) Just a small detail, you can eliminate the `slide.shapes._spTree.remove()` line. In `lxml` when you insert an element somewhere, it comes out of it's old position to take the new position. This question of how to adjust z-order of shapes comes up a lot and this is a very helpful solution :)